# Unable to locate element with Selenium that is clearly there

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

So I am working on a program that will buy an item from target online, once it is in stock, using Selenium and chromedriver.

However, I can't seem to locate a certain button, and I'm not sure why; it always comes up with the error message, "no such element: Unable to locate element."

The button in question is the "View cart & checkout button".

Here's the code I have right now, though I've tried locating it by xpath as well and it comes up with the same message.

```
time.sleep(10)
addtocartstr= 'body > div:nth-child(46) > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.Row-sc-uds8za-0.iNenuU.h-margin-v-default > div:nth-child(3) > button'
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, addtocartstr).click()
```

I've been using this glue to test my program: https://www.target.com/p/elmer-39-s-1gal-washable-school-glue-white/-/A-47987964
If you click "Ship it", the button in question will pop up.

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

Was able to click on the <kbd>View cart & checkout</kbd> button with below code. Try the below locators for the same.
And better to apply some waits.

```
# Imports required
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.get("https://www.target.com/p/elmer-39-s-1gal-washable-school-glue-white/-/A-47987964")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Click on "Ship it"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-test='shipItButton']"))).click()

# Click on "View cart & checkout"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@data-test='addToCartModalViewCartCheckout']"))).click()
```

Comment: @Smoothie - If the answer was helpful, accept the same.